# Can I use my phonegap app as an image chooser on android?

Tags: android, jquery, image, cordova

I have a phonegap app in which you can really easily sort your images and videos, however, I want to be able to let a user choose an image from my app, just as he would choose an image in the gallery.

For example, if he wanted to share an image via WhatsApp or Facebook, you have a button which allows you to add an image. On Android, you will then be able to choose between 'Gallery' and 'Images' (similar app from Google I suppose). After that, you will be taken to the one you've chosen, and then you can pick an image.

Now I want my app to function as the gallery, or at least be an option in this list. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cordova plugins for this purpose. There are options available:

1. [Camera Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera): Behaves like the Gallery, but may have memory problems on old devices.
2. [Image Picker Plugin](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker): A simple one to pick an image.

Both of them are also available by using [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/) (a wrapper around common plugins)